# How can I edit get function of Java-Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, get

Netbeans autogenerates the `get()` function, but my application doen't run if the `return` doesn't have the `this`.

Incorrect:

```
public String getStringVariable(){
    return stringVariable;
}
```

Correct:

```
public String getStringVariable(){
    return this.stringVariable;
}
```

As I work with many (many) variables its difficult write `this` in each `get`. I found I can change `App.java` but I don't know its location (http://www.fordfrog.com/2010/07/19/modifying-netbeans-generated-getters-and-setters/)

Thank you!

Comment: "my application doen't run if the return doesn't have the this" - isn't that the real problem? Everything else is just a workaround...

Comment: I'm having trouble envisioning a class where the `this.` makes a difference, since you have no parameter or local variable names that conflict with `stringVariable`.  What does the rest of your class look like?